# AngularJS - Pass variable from a controller & update from directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

I've set one [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/SVOWqI?p=preview). I want to dynamically add input fields in a directive. The input fields are to be built by a collection from a controller. And change the values of the inputs. But the main problem is that I can't edit the values in input fields generated by the directive.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shortly: bind to objects instead text values.

Longer: see your forked Plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/wzfwQI

See comments which starts from "Changes:" in `script.js` and `dynamicTextFields-template.html`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It saved me a lot of pain.